# Подключение js/css в Symfony4

Tags: webpack, symfony

Помогите разобраться с подключением js/css в Symfony4 с Webpack Encore.
Пытаюсь подключить [adminlte](https://adminlte.io/docs/2.4/installation) для админки.
Скачиваю его через npm в node_modules и ... как действовать дальше, чтобы использовать скрипты и стили в шаблонах?

Со скриптами, если понимаю правильно, просто - создаем в assets/js файл, подключаем в нем

```
var adminlte=require('admin-lte');
```

и в шаблон подключаем сгенерированный через webpack файл.
А вот как подключать стили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В шаблоне подключаем собранные вебпаком файлы (public/build):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
```

В `app.js` и `app.css` будут включены все файлы используемые в проекте, в том числе и из node_modules.

Подключить css в `app.js` можно примерно так:

```
require('admin-lte/dist/AdminLTE.min.css')
```